# Is it possible to center windows forms with vba?

Tags: vba

My VBA macro is formatting a USB drive before it copies data on it. 
The whole process is already working quite good.
So the problem is, that the Windows Format Tool window is opening somewhere on the top left corner of the screen and not like I want it, centered and pretty in the middle of the screen.

So is there a possibility to open them centered or if not, is there anything to center them afterwards?

This is how the window starts:

```
Private Sub format_drive(selected_volume)        
    Dim Result&, Drive&
    varray = Split(selected_volume, ":")
    Drive = Asc(varray(0)) - 65
    Result = SHFormatDrive(0, Drive, SHFD_CAPACITY_DEFAULT, SHFD_FORMAT_QUICK)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what your windows format tool window is? Is it a normal Excel Userform?

Comment: It's the standard windows 10 form thats oppening when you want to format a USB Drive with a right click in the context menu. So there is no coustom userform involved.

Comment: And how do you make it to appear?

Comment: Added the code to question.

Comment: The very first paragraph under Parameters [reads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shformatdrive#parameters), *"The handle of the parent window of the dialog box. The Format dialog box must have a parent window; therefore, this parameter cannot be `NULL`."* Pass `Application.Hwnd` there.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a macro then there must be a parent application, most probably Excel. When a userform is launched from under Excel, the form will be positioned within the active window (that may be maximized). If you want to change the position of your form taylor the following sample to your needs:

```
Private Sub UserForm_initialize()

     Me.Show vbModeless

     With Me                 ' this must come after .Show
         .Top = (Abs(Application.Top) + Application.Height - .Height)/2
         .Left = (Abs(Application.Left) + ActiveWindow.Width - .Width)/2
     End With
```

`Application.Top` can be negativ, `Abs()` is applied to handle it. It's not the most correct yet it's safe. Alternatively you can use `ActiveWindows`:

```
    With Me
        .Top = (Application.ActiveWindow.Height - .Height)/2
        .Left = (Application.ActiveWindow.Width - .Width)/2
    End With
```

At an advanced level you can use `GetDeviceCaps(HDC hdc, HORZRES)` and `GetDeviceCaps(HDC hdc, VERTRES)` to get the number of pixels of your screen. See this for more: [GetDeviceCaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps)

Comment: [*"It's the standard windows 10 form thats oppening when you want to format a USB Drive with a right click in the context menu. So there is no coustom userform involved."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887123/is-it-possible-to-center-windows-forms-with-vba#comment92687755_52887123)